# Getting data of HTML DIV tag without using Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, html

Hello to all respected Experts,

I've one question regarding to C#.net. What i wanna do is that basically i have one HTML page
and i wanna extract data from it's DIV tag this is the sample of HTML :

```
<div class="clr fleft">     
    <strong class="xx-large">033 111 22222</strong>
</div>
```

Now  I wanna Get those numbers which are inside of "xx-large" Tag.
I want some help in doing it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you specify what you've tried this far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlstring);
```

using XPATH,

```
var data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='xx-large']").InnerText;
```

using Linq,

```
var data = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
            .Where(x => x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "xx-large")
            .First()
            .InnerText;
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks For This Piece Of Code, I'm Gonna Try It And Should Inform About The Result.

Answer (score 1):

As i know, you cant access them just by c# (your server-side codes). You must write some javascript codes to do this. (your javascript code can have no regex)

Comment: I've seen some data scrapping tools they're doing that very well i know i can make a webrequest and get html of the page after it i want data inside of the class "xx-large" .

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a library with predefined parsers. You can use Beautiful Soup parser (originally written in python, can be interfaced with C#) see how it's done http://ashomtwit.espace-technologies.com/4499480-BeautifulSoup_and_ASP_NET_C_.html or you can choose an alternative package. These library has the predefined regular expression and has methods to open web pages to collect the information. It is so simple to use this.